# Play video in Android webview - Video controls not visible

Tags: android

I am working on hybrid application, where i need to play video on android browser.
Video is playing/pausing fine, but video controls are not visible on video view.

Below is the code Snippet for android web view settings to make video working -

Java Code :

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);

webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Also i added android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in application tag in Manifest file.

HTML code for Video tag :

```
<video id="videoContainer" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"  src="file:///mnt/sdcard/8.mp4" height="400" width="400" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Please let me know is anything more to add in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the issue, but it was strange experience.
The issue was with Style which i applied for Buttons on screen and same effect get applied to Video control's, thats why video player buttons get transparent and not visible to user.